# C# selenium instagram login issue

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

Hi everyone recently my mom created instagram account for his work and I want to make him auto follower bot in selenium but whenever I try to test this few times instagram just locks me out by saying Please try again in few minutes but It just keeps saying after 5-10-20 minutes even hours any suggestions ? How can I test this ?
With this code just logs in and scroll down in main page where you can follow people by randomly but I cant follow all of them , how can I adress follow button every time ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace InstagramFollower
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly string Pusername = "sorrycantshare";
        private static readonly string Ppassword = "sorrycantshare";
        private static int sayac = 1;
        public static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        static void Main()
        {
           
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com/");
            //driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Console.WriteLine("Siteye  açıldı");
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("username")));          
            IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
            IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
            IWebElement loginbtn = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".Igw0E.IwRSH.eGOV_._4EzTm"));           
            username.SendKeys(Pusername);
            password.SendKeys(Ppassword);
            loginbtn.Click();
            Console.WriteLine("Hesaba giriş yapıldı");
            ElementToClickableCssSelector(".sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"https://www.instagram.com");
            Console.WriteLine("Anasayfaya yönlendirildi");
            ElementToClickableCssSelector(".aOOlW.HoLwm");
            IWebElement notNow = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".aOOlW.HoLwm"));
            notNow.Click();
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
            Thread.Sleep(2500);
            ElementToClickableCssSelector(".Szr5J._6CZji");                 
                Listpeople();
            Thread.Sleep(3500);


            /*
            IWebElement followbtn = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".sqdOP.L3NKy._4pI4F.y3zKF"));
            followbtn.Click(); // It follows first person on line but It gives error for others.
            */
        }

        public static void Listpeople()
        {
            
            IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> followersname = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".FPmhX.notranslate.Qj3-a"));
            IWebElement nextbtn = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".Szr5J._6CZji"));
            foreach (IWebElement follower in followersname)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sayac.ToString() + " ==> " + follower.Text);
                sayac++;
                if (sayac == 8)
                {
                    nextbtn.Click();
                }
            }
        }
        public static void ElementToClickableCssSelector(string target)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(target)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're creating a bot that follows someone on instagram? It's probably some kind of protection against this exact thing you're trying to create. Chances are Selenium uses a modified user agent which Instagram detects and blocks.

Comment: I believe instragram developers are doing everything they could to prevent exactly this kind of abuse of their service. And there should be high competion (probably illegal) and demand for a working software like this.

Comment: @Sinatr I dont think there is demand for working software like this because its is easy to produce and and I just want him to follow people , morally speaking I dont think its abuse but anyway
Devilscomrade It worked in many times but after many logs in and exits it probably detects this way.

Comment: Read about bots [here](https://www.ampfluence.com/why-does-instagram-block-me-from-following-people/).

Answer (score 0):

Well I had to read some topics about it turns out instagram detects selenium webdriver but I belive in my case is different.Reason I got error of please try again in later is beacuse my account does not log out , every time I log in and test after I stop building and shutdown cmd and browser so It doesnt log out.I am now writing a void to log out for after I test it